# OpenGL - Calculating camera view matrix

Tags: opengl, camera, matrix, opentk

**Problem**

I am calculating the model, view and projection matrices independently to be used in my shader as follows:

```
gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
```

When I try to calculate my camera's view matrix the Z axis is flipped and my camera seems like it is looking backwards.

My program is written in C# using the OpenTK library.

**Translation (Working)**

I've created a test scene as follows:

[image] [image]

From my understanding of the OpenGL coordinate system they are positioned correctly.

The **model** matrix is created using:

```
Matrix4 translation = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
Matrix4 model = translation;
```

The **view** matrix is created using:

```
Matrix4 translation = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(-cameraPosition);
Matrix4 view = translation;
```

**Rotation (Not-Working)**

I now want to create the camera's rotation matrix.  To do this I use the camera's right, up and forward vectors:

```
// Hard coded example orientation:
// Normally calculated from up and forward
// Similar to look-at camera.
Vector3 r = Vector.UnitX;
Vector3 u = Vector3.UnitY;
Vector3 f = -Vector3.UnitZ;

Matrix4 rot = new Matrix4(
    r.X, r.Y, r.Z, 0,
    u.X, u.Y, u.Z, 0,
    f.X, f.Y, f.Z, 0,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

This results in the following matrix being created:

[image]

I know that multiplying by the identity matrix would produce no rotation.  This is clearly not the identity matrix and therefore will apply some rotation.

I thought that because this is aligned with the OpenGL coordinate system is should produce no rotation.  Is this the wrong way to calculate the rotation matrix?

I then create my view matrix as:

```
// OpenTK is row-major so the order of operations is reversed:
Matrix4 view = translation * rot;
```

Rotation almost works now but the -Z/+Z axis has been flipped, with the green cube now appearing closer to the camera.  **It seems like the camera is looking backwards**, especially if I move it around.

My goal is to store the position and orientation of all objects (including the camera) as:

```
Vector3 position;
Vector3 up;
Vector3 forward;
```

Apologies for writing such a long question and thank you in advance.  I've tried following tutorials/guides from many sites but I keep ending up with something wrong.

**Edit: Projection Matrix Set-up**

```
Matrix4 projection = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
    (float)(0.5 * Math.PI),
    (float)display.Width / display.Height,
    0.1f,
    1000.0f);
```

Comment: There is a part of this process that you are currently ignoring. OpenGL does ***not*** mandate anything about any of the axes in coordinate spaces prior to clip-space in the programmable pipeline. Clip-space is left-handed, and the *only* way to achieve this is if your projection matrix flips the Z-axis, given your current view-space setup. *Can you show the setup of your projection matrix?*

Comment: I've added the projection matrix set-up to the original post, thanks.

Comment: Considering that OpenTK is row-major and the function you are calling shares its name with a D3D function... I would not be surprised if that produces a projection matrix that expects left-handed view-space coordinates (D3D convention). If you call `Matrix4.Perspective (...)` instead, does anything change?

Comment: I tried calling Matrix4.Perspective(...) with the same arguments and it produced the same matrix (ignoring very small rounding errors).  The documentation marks the method as deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that constructing the matrix out of the right, up, and forward vectors inherently sets up coordinates in which X points right, Y points up, and Z points forward.  The Z axis in this coordinate system points the opposite of the direction it's "supposed" to point (for right-handed view space, as seen in your first diagram).

To fix the problem, you just need to build the view matrix using the camera's right, up, and *backward* (negative forward) vectors instead.